# UnsatisfiedDependencyException/circular reference error when starting Tomcat context

Tags: javabeans

I get the following error when starting Tomcat context:

```
Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'adminService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'adminServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
```

Comment: Please format your code and question more clearly.

Comment: It sounds like one of the beans is trying to import itself (probably via another service that contains it), causing a loop. I'd look through the services in the error to find that. If you want more help, I'd suggest posting the code for the services listed in the error output.

Comment: The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

┌─────┐
|  securityConfig (field private com.xxxx.server.service.impl.IAdminService com.xxxx.server.config.security.SecurityConfig.adminService)
↑     ↓
|  adminServiceImpl (field private org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService com.xxxx.server.service.impl.impl.AdminServiceImpl.userDetailsService)
└─────┘